# ORACLE SQL - combine two tables and group the results based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. Heres an example :

Employees Table

```
EMP_ID - NAME - SURNAME - DEPART_NAME

  1    - JOHN -  JOHN   - Accounting
```

Managers Table

```
MANAGER_ID - NAME - SURNAME - DEPART_NAME

    1      - Nick -   Nick    -   IT
```

I want to output something like this

```
Accounting   |    IT 
-------------|--------------
John John    | Nick Nick
```

Of course there will be more than IT or accounting department. How can i do that? i tried with UNION and GROUP BY but i cant make it to work

Comment: So, why exactly `John` and `Nick` are on the same row? What does the row represent in your resulting table?

Comment: What business rule does that output represent? There's no link between the two tables. Perhaps you need something like a MANAGER_ID on the Employees table.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do ? Maybe its simplier to UNION both tables and order them by Department Name?

Comment: Depends, on what are you trying to achieve... be more specific - what is your end goal.

Comment: This makes no sense (and I recall a similar question asked here recently by the OP.) Why would there be an `emp_id` and a separate `mgr_id`? Managers are employees, and they have an employee id themselves. Where did you find this data model? Surely not in real life, and if it's in class notes or a textbook, you should ask for your money back.

Comment: Hmmm  "maybe its simplier" ... to do something which produces a different output? Well all sorts of things might be simpler. The thing is, what are you trying to achieve?